# How to send Mirth HTTP connector using POST

Tags: web-services, mirth

We have a mirth instance sending out using a POST method to a rest service.

However, Mirth seems to be sending at least one parameter through the URL (like a GET) instead.

We have the following options set:

Method: POST
Multipart: No
Send Response to: none
Response Content: Headers and Body as XML
Authentication: No
Use Persistent Queues: No
Charset Encoding: UTF-8

Then we have 5 query parameters -

One of which is the name "file" and value of "${message.rawData}".  I am watching the Apache request log and can see this attribute/value pair come across the URL (as if it were doing a GET instead of a POST).

No headers

Content Type text/plain
Content: literal "no data."

We are using Mirth Connect Server 2.2.1.5861

How do I force this value ('file') to come across the POST?

Comment: See my proposal for HealthcareIT as a StackExchange site where this question would be a great fit: area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51758/healthcare-it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While @Dave's response made sense, it didn't actually work for me.  But it did send me down the path of further investigation.

The biggest key was that in order send the list attribute/values pairs as a "post" in the "web form processing" sense,  you need to do this:

Set the payload "type" to:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

This forces all elements to be "post'ed".  If you want a mix bag (which for reasons known only to purest is "bad form") then you need to jump through more hoops.

See the following link for details:

[Mirth Forums Thread related to accessing a RESTful web service](http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/forums/showthread.php?t=6194)

Comment: See my proposal for HealthcareIT as a StackExchange site where this question would be a great fit:
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51758/healthcare-it

Answer (score 1):

Query parameters in mirth are URL parameters.  Therefore it's going to come across similar to  a Get.  If you want to Post variables you need to encode them in the 'Content' section of the http sender.

I believe it follows a similar encoding, though you may want to look into it further

```
lastName=Smith&age=31&team=woodchucks
```

So you would probably want something like:

```
file=${message.rawData}
```

Comment: yes, that would make sense, but I have yet to get it work.  I'm just using hard-coded values and still nothing across the POST section....I'll keep hacking at it...

Comment: This is not true for Mirth 3.x where it depends on the Content Type field (see accepted answer). The value application/x-www-form-urlencoded moves the values from querystring to post parameters.